# How to change a position of element when a window size changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a simple search's form in HTML:

```
<div class="mainWindow">
    <form action="#">
        <input type="text" id="query" placeholder="Search..." autofocus required />
        <input type="button" id="button" value="SEARCH" />
    </form>
</div>
```

I use the jQuery's code for change the default position mainWindow's div to center of the window:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    mainWindowInCenter();
});

function mainWindowInCenter() {
    $('.mainWindow').css('position','fixed');
    $('.mainWindow').css("left", ($(window).width()/2-$('.mainWindow').width()/2) + "px");
    $('.mainWindow').css("top", ($(window).height()/2-$('.mainWindow').height()/2) + "px");
};
```

but **it works only one time** and when I change my browser's window, the div stay in the same position after the script.

What I need to do that the div change it position all times when the window's size is changing too?
Can I trace the window's resize somehow? Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (window.size.isChange()) {
    mainWindowInCenter();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call your function whenever the window is resized by hooking to the `resize` event:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  mainWindowInCenter();
});

function mainWindowInCenter() {
  $('.mainWindow').css({
    position: 'fixed',
    left: $(window).width() / 2 - $('.mainWindow').width() / 2,
    top: $(window).height() / 2 - $('.mainWindow').height() / 2
  });
}
```

You may also be able to achieve the same effect using CSS alone, which would be much more preferable. However whether or not that's possible would depend on your HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use any javascript for that.

If your element is with static width/height, you should just can give it the following css:

```
.mainWindow {
    position: fixed;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px; /* Negative half of height. */
    margin-left: -250px; /* Negative half of width. */
}
```

And it would just be centered, regardless of window events, and will save you from performance issues when binding to the `resize` event.